# metrics-server CrashLoopBackOff on k8s v1.11.1

Tags: kubernetes, metrics

Using `kubeadm` and `flannel` over 4-nodes running on `RHEL 7`

I did the following:

- Open port 10250 on all nodes
- Applied [Failed to get kubernetes address: No kubernetes source found](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server/issues/97) to address `no source found` issue
- Ran `kubectl create -f deploy/1.8+/`
- Ran `kubectl get pods -n=kube-system`

and then got `CrashLoopBackOff` on metrics-server

```
NAME                                          READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-78fcdf6894-4q7ct                      1/1       Running            10         7d
coredns-78fcdf6894-7tj52                      1/1       Running            10         7d
etcd-thalia0.ahc.umn.edu                      1/1       Running            0          7d
kube-apiserver-thalia0.ahc.umn.edu            1/1       Running            0          7d
kube-controller-manager-thalia0.ahc.umn.edu   1/1       Running            0          7d
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-78hbk                   1/1       Running            0          7d
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-gdttr                   1/1       Running            0          7d
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-rzhm2                   1/1       Running            0          7d
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-xc2n7                   1/1       Running            0          7d
kube-proxy-b86kn                              1/1       Running            0          7d
kube-proxy-g27sk                              1/1       Running            0          7d
kube-proxy-rtgtp                              1/1       Running            0          7d
kube-proxy-x2pp7                              1/1       Running            0          7d
kube-scheduler-thalia0.ahc.umn.edu            1/1       Running            0          7d
kubernetes-dashboard-7b7cb74c5c-wgt8f         1/1       Running            0          6d
metrics-server-85ff8f7b84-2x5th               0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   8          23m
```

5. Ran `kubectl -n kube-system logs $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=metrics-server -o name)`

and got output:

```
I0828 19:26:41.686932       1 heapster.go:71] /metrics-server --source=kubernetes:https://kubernetes.default
I0828 19:26:41.687023       1 heapster.go:72] Metrics Server version v0.2.1
I0828 19:26:41.687360       1 configs.go:61] Using Kubernetes client with master "https://kubernetes.default" and version
I0828 19:26:41.687388       1 configs.go:62] Using kubelet port 10255
E0828 19:27:01.692571       1 kubelet.go:331] Failed to load nodes: Get https://kubernetes.default/api/v1/nodes: dial tcp: lookup kubernetes.default on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.2.4:34644->10.96.0.10:53: read: no route to host
I0828 19:27:01.692700       1 heapster.go:128] Starting with Metric Sink
I0828 19:27:02.500852       1 serving.go:308] Generated self-signed cert (apiserver.local.config/certificates/apiserver.crt, apiserver.local.config/certificates/apiserver.key)
W0828 19:27:04.381151       1 authentication.go:222] Unable to get configmap/extension-apiserver-authentication in kube-system.  Usually fixed by 'kubectl create rolebinding -n kube-system ROLE_NAME --role=extension-apiserver-authentication-reader --serviceaccount=YOUR_NS:YOUR_SA'
F0828 19:27:04.381187       1 heapster.go:97] Could not create the API server: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/extension-apiserver-authentication: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: getsockopt: no route to host
```

I also looked at the various logs, and noticed for the `flannel` pods I was getting a whole slew of these errors:

```
E0829 19:41:32.636680       1 reflector.go:201] github.com/coreos/flannel/subnet/kube/kube.go:295: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/nodes?resourceVersion=0: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

Also, getting this error on the scheduler pod:

```
E0829 19:41:32.637368       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/informers/informers_generated/internalversion/factory.go:129: Failed to list *core.Service: Get https://134.84.53.162:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

**EDIT 1**

I rebuilt the cluster after tearing in down and adding a rule on the local firewall to allow port 443 (for dealing with `kubectl proxy`).

Output of `kubectl get services --namespace=kube-system` is

```
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
kube-dns               ClusterIP   10.96.0.10     <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   15h
kubernetes-dashboard   ClusterIP   10.98.72.170   <none>        443/TCP         20m
metrics-server         ClusterIP   10.111.155.9   <none>        443/TCP         1m
```

Also, of note, after the teardown and reinitialization of the cluster, both the flannel and scheduler pods are not throwing the error. I'm Only getting the error on the metrics-server pod, along with this new error on the apiserver pod:

```
: service unavailable
, Header: map[Content-Type:[text/plain; charset=utf-8] X-Content-Type-Options:[nosniff]]
I0830 20:43:38.101286       1 controller.go:119] OpenAPI AggregationController: action for item v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io: Rate Limited Requeue.
I0830 20:45:38.101548       1 controller.go:105] OpenAPI AggregationController: Processing item v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io
E0830 20:45:38.101757       1 controller.go:111] loading OpenAPI spec for "v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io" failed with: failed to retrieve openAPI spec, http error: ResponseCode: 503, Body: service unavailable
, Header: map[Content-Type:[text/plain; charset=utf-8] X-Content-Type-Options:[nosniff]]
I0830 20:45:38.101779       1 controller.go:119] OpenAPI AggregationController: action for item v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io: Rate Limited Requeue.
E0830 20:45:44.532250       1 available_controller.go:311] v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io failed with: Get https://10.111.155.9:443: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
I0830 20:45:48.894505       1 controller.go:105] OpenAPI AggregationController: Processing item v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io
E0830 20:45:48.894693       1 controller.go:111] loading OpenAPI spec for "v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io" failed with: failed to retrieve openAPI spec, http error: ResponseCode: 503, Body: service unavailable
```

Furthermore, digging into the error  `W0828 19:27:04.381151       1 authentication.go:222] Unable to get configmap/extension-apiserver-authentication in kube-system.  Usually fixed by 'kubectl create rolebinding -n kube-system ROLE_NAME --role=extension-apiserver-authentication-reader --serviceaccount=YOUR_NS:YOUR_SA'`

I ran `kubectl get roles -n kube-system extension-apiserver-authentication-reader -o yaml` and got the following output:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  annotations:
    rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: "true"
  creationTimestamp: 2018-08-30T00:58:35Z
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/bootstrapping: rbac-defaults
  name: extension-apiserver-authentication-reader
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "132"
  selfLink: /apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-system/roles/extension-apiserver-authentication-reader
  uid: d2f1c80c-abef-11e8-95cc-005056891f42
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resourceNames:
  - extension-apiserver-authentication
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs:
  - get
```

Lastly, the output `kubectl get apiservice v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io -o yaml` of is

```
apiVersion: apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: APIService
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-08-30T22:41:26Z
  name: v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io
  resourceVersion: "119754"
  selfLink: /apis/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1/apiservices/v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io
  uid: d403e18f-aca5-11e8-95cc-005056891f42
spec:
  group: metrics.k8s.io
  groupPriorityMinimum: 100
  insecureSkipTLSVerify: true
  service:
    name: metrics-server
    namespace: kube-system
  version: v1beta1
  versionPriority: 100
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: 2018-08-30T22:41:26Z
    message: endpoints for service/metrics-server in "kube-system" have no addresses
    reason: MissingEndpoints
    status: "False"
    type: Available
```

This seems like an obvious network problem (firewall?), but I am not sure how to proceed with this. Is this a `flannel` or a `coredns` configuration issue?

Comment: Could you add output `kubectl get services --namespace=kube-system` looks like it is problem internal with services.

Comment: Updated with this information above.

Comment: Did you find any solution with flannel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched the CNI from `flannel` to `calico` and that seems to have resolved the problems I was having (I was also unable to get the `argo workflow` controller to fire up in my cluster).